# C# - invalid outputs

Tags: c#, enums

I am using `enums` in C# to calculate the areas of different shapes. Below is my code:

```
using System;
class Area
{
    public enum Shape{Circle,Square};
    public void AreaShape(int x,Shape ob1)
    {
        double a;
        switch(x)
        {
            case (int)Shape.Circle:
                a=Math.PI*x*x;
                Console.WriteLine("Circle "+a);
                break;
            case (int)Shape.Square:
                a=x*x;
                Console.WriteLine("Square "+a);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                break;
        }
    }
}
class MyTestOne
{
    public static void Main(String[] a)
    {
        Area obj1=new Area();
        obj1.AreaShape(15,Area.Shape.Circle);
        obj1.AreaShape(15,Area.Shape.Square);
    }
}
```

The following produces an error:

```
obj1.AreaShape(15,Shape.Circle);
obj1.AreaShape(15,Shape.Square);
```

How can I get the following output?

```
Circle 225*pi
Square 225
```

When I use `Area.Shape.Circle` and `Area.Shape.Square`, the output is:

```
Invalid
Invalid
```

Comment: You are switching on the `x` parameter, I think you want to switch on `ob1`?

Comment: Should your `switch` be changed to `switch(ob1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Shape enum class not int x variable

```
            switch (ob1)
            {
                case Shape.Circle:
                    a = Math.PI * x * x;
                    Console.WriteLine("Circle " + a);
                    break;
                case Shape.Square:
                    a = x * x;
                    Console.WriteLine("Square " + a);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks...It Worked

Comment: Can u tell why we use Area.Shape.Circle and not Shape.Circle ?

Comment: Because you defined enum in Area class. Take enum out of Area class and you'll see *Area.Shape.Circle* will no longer valid. :) edit : typo

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` statement switches on `x`, which you're always passing in as `15`. You should be switching on the `ob1` enumeration variable and you won't need the cast.